A bound for the recurrence relation $x_{k+1}\leq x_{k}-x_{k+1}^{1+\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha\leq 1$

Suppose I have a sequence $\{x_k\}$ of positive real numbers that satisfies
$$x_{k+1}\leq x_k-x_{k+1}^{1+\alpha}$$
for $0<\alpha\leq 1$. Prove for $k\geq 0$:
$$x_{k}\leq \frac{x_0}{\left(1+\frac{\alpha k}{1+\alpha}\log(1+x_0^{\alpha})\right)^{1/\alpha}}.$$

Here's what I tried:
Note that $x_{k+1}+x_{k+1}^{1+\alpha}=x_{k+1}(1+x_{k+1}^{\alpha})\leq x_k.$ My plan is to use induction. To do that, we have
$$x_{k+1}(1+x_{k+1}^{\alpha})\leq \frac{x_0}{\left(1+\frac{\alpha k}{1+\alpha}\log(1+x_0^{\alpha})\right)^{1/\alpha}}.$$
so taking log gets
$$\log(x_{k+1})+\log(1+x_{k+1}^{\alpha})\leq \log(x_0)-\frac{1}{\alpha}\log\left(1+\frac{\alpha k}{1+\alpha}\log(1+x_0^{\alpha})\right)$$
Now I am stuck because I don't know how to deal with the left hand side. Any hints?

You can't prove it, because it's not true. E.g. let $x_0=-1\wedge\alpha=1$, then you would have to take the logarithm of $0$ which is not defined. If $x_0$ is negative then $x_0^\alpha\wedge\alpha\ne1$ would be a non-real complex number aka the RHS would also be not real. Maybe there is a typo in the conditions (e.g. the title says "$0<\alpha<1$" but the text beneath it says "$0<\alpha\leq1$")?

The $\alpha$ can include 1. Also the $x_n$ is assumed to be nonnegative.

The following two lemmas come handy:

Lemma 1. Assume $\gamma \in [0, 1]$, $\beta > 0$, and $L \geq 0$. Then
$$ (1 + \gamma L)^{1/\beta} \leq 1 + \gamma(e^{L/\beta} - 1). \tag{1}\label{e:ineq1} $$


Lemma 2. Assume $\alpha > 0$ and define $f(z) = z(1+z)^{\alpha}$. Let $\beta = \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}$. Then $f$ is strictly increasing, and for any $w \geq 0$,
$$ f^{-1}(w) \leq \frac{w}{(1+w)^\beta}. \tag{2}\label{e:ineq2} $$

Now, let $z_k = x_k^{\alpha}$, and $f$ and $\beta$ be as in Lemma 2. Then by $\eqref{e:ineq2}$,
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} \leq x_k - x_{k+1}^{\alpha+1}
&\iff f(z_{k+1}) \leq z_k \\
&\iff z_{k+1} \leq f^{-1}(z_k) \\
&\implies z_{k+1} \leq \frac{z_k}{(1+z_k)^{\beta}}. \tag{3}\label{e:equiv}
\end{align*}
Moreover, what OP wants to show, $x_k \leq \frac{x_0}{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha k}{\alpha+1} \log(1+x_0^\alpha) \right)^{1/\alpha}}$, is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
z_k \leq \frac{z_0}{1+ kL}, \tag{$\star$}\label{e:wts}
\end{align*}
where $L = \beta \log(1+z_0)$, or equivalently, $z_0 = e^{L/\beta} - 1$. So, it suffices to prove that $\eqref{e:wts}$ by induction.

Base case. When $k = 0$, both sides of $\eqref{e:wts}$ are identically $z_0$, hence the (in)equality holds.

Inductive step. Assume $\eqref{e:wts}$ holds for a given $k \geq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
z_{k+1}
\leq \frac{z_k}{(1 + z_k)^\beta}
\leq \frac{\left( \frac{z_0}{1+ kL} \right)}{\left(1 + \frac{z_0}{1+ kL} \right)^\beta}. \tag{4}\label{e:4}
\end{align*}
Here, the first step follows from $\eqref{e:equiv}$ and the second step follows from the monotonicity of $w \mapsto \frac{w}{(1+w)^\beta}$ and the induction hypothesis. Now, let $\gamma = \frac{1}{1 + k L} \in [0, 1]$. Then
\begin{align*}
\text{[RHS of $\eqref{e:4}$]} = \frac{z_0 \gamma}{(1 + z_0 \gamma )^\beta},
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_0}{1+\beta (k+1) \log(1+z_0)}
&= \frac{z_0 \gamma}{1 + \gamma L}.
\end{align*}
Hence, the induction step is established once we prove:
$$ \frac{z_0 \gamma}{(1 + z_0 \gamma )^\beta} \leq \frac{z_0 \gamma}{1 + \gamma L}. \tag{5}\label{e:5} $$
However,
\begin{align*}
\eqref{e:5}
&\iff 1 + \gamma L \leq (1 + z_0 \gamma )^\beta \\
&\iff (1 + \gamma L)^{1/\beta} \leq 1 + \gamma(e^{L/\beta} - 1).
\end{align*}
Note that the last inequality is precisely $\eqref{e:ineq1}$. Therefore the induction step is proved.


Therefore the desired relation follows. $\square$

Remark. Interestingly, this proof works only if $\alpha > 0$, and this is indeed confirmed by numerical experiments.


Proof of Lemma 1. This follows from
\begin{align*}
(1 + \gamma L)^{1/\beta}
&\leq  e^{\gamma L/\beta} \\
&= (1 + (e^{L/\beta} - 1))^{\gamma} \\
&\leq 1 + \gamma (e^{L/\beta} - 1).
\end{align*}
Below is a more detailed explanations:

The first inequality follows from $1 + x \leq e^x$, which holds for any real $x$.
The second inequality follows from $(1 + x)^\gamma \leq 1 + \gamma x$, which holds for any $x \geq -1$. Indeed, this inequality is an easy consequence of the concavity of $x \mapsto (1 + x)^{\gamma}$.

Proof of Lemma 2. From the definition, it is clear that $f$ is strictly increasing. Next, let $w \geq 0$ and $z = f^{-1}(w) \geq 0$. Then it is easy to check that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(w) \leq \frac{w}{(1+w)^\beta}
\iff z \leq \frac{f(z)}{(1+f(z))^\beta}
\iff 1 \leq (1+z)^{\alpha},
\end{align*}
which holds true.

It seems $f=z(1+z^\alpha)$  here , not $z(1+z)^\alpha$, otherwise $\beta=1/2$.

@EDX, Substituting $z_k=x_k^{\alpha}$ to $$ \left[ x_{k+1}(1+x_{k+1}^{\alpha}) \right]^{\alpha} \leq [x_k]^{\alpha} $$ leads to $z_{k+1}(1+z_{k+1})^{\alpha}\leq z_k$, so I think $f(z)=z(1+z)^{\alpha}$ is the right choice.

Ok brilliant thx for the answer

The result $z(1 + z)^\alpha \le w \implies z \le \frac{w}{(1 + w)^{\alpha/(1 + \alpha)}}$ is very nice.
The key step is to find some appropriate $g(w)$ such that $z(1 + z)^\alpha \le w \implies z \le g(w)$. I can find some complicated form of $g(w)$ (numerical simulation shows perhaps it works for the Mathematical Induction Process).

I failed to prove the required inequality but simplified it. So I post my try hoping that it can help to answer the question.
For each nonnegative integer $k$ put $y_k=x_k^\alpha$. Then we have $y_{k+1}(1+y_{k+1})^\alpha\le y_k$ and
we have to prove that $y_{k}\leq \frac{y_0}{1+kC}$, where $C=\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\log(1+y_0)$.
Let us try to proceed by induction on $k$. For $k=0$ the required inequality is trivial. For the induction step it suffices to show that
$$\frac{y_0}{1+(k+1)C}\left(1+\frac{y_0}{1+(k+1)C}\right)^\alpha\ge \frac{y_0}{1+kC},$$
that is
$$\left(1+\frac{y_0}{1+(k+1)C}\right)^\alpha\ge 1+\frac{C}{1+kC}.$$

Alternative solution.
Consider the sequence $\{w_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ of positive numbers defined by:
$w_0 = x_0$, and $w_{k+1} = w_k - w_{k+1}^{1+\alpha}$ for $k=0, 1, 2, \cdots$.
It is easy to prove that $x_k \le w_k$ for $k = 0, 1, \cdots$ by the Mathematical Induction.
Then it suffices to prove that, for all $k\ge 0$,
$$w_k \le \frac{w_0}{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot k\right)^{1/\alpha}}. \tag{1}$$
We use the Mathematical Induction to prove (1).
The statement is clearly true for $k=0$.
Assume that the statement is true for $k$ ($k\ge 0$).
For $k + 1$, it suffices to prove that
$$w_{k+1} \le \frac{w_0}{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot (k+1)\right)^{1/\alpha}}.$$
Let $u := \frac{w_{k+1}}{w_k} \in (0, 1)$.
We have $u w_k + u^{1+\alpha}w_k^{1+\alpha} = w_k$
and then $u + u^{1+\alpha}w_k^{\alpha} =1$ which results in
$$w_k = \frac{(1 - u)^{1/\alpha}}{u^{(1+\alpha)/\alpha}}, \quad w_{k+1} = \frac{(1 - u)^{1/\alpha}}{u^{1/\alpha}}. \tag{2}$$
Using (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1 - u}{u}
\le \frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot (k+1)},$$
or
$$\frac{1}{u}
\le 1 + \frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot (k+1)}. \tag{3}$$
By the inductive hypothesis, we have
$$\frac{1 - u}{u^{1+\alpha}} \le \frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot k}, $$
or
$$\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^\alpha\left(\frac{1}{u} - 1\right)
\le \frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot k}. \tag{4}$$
From (3) and (4), since $v \to v^\alpha (v - 1)$ is strictly increasing on $v \ge 1$, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left(1 + \frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot (k+1)}\right)^\alpha\left(\frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot (k+1)}\right)\\
 \ge{}& \frac{w_0^\alpha}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot k}.\tag{5}
\end{align*}
(5) is true. The proof is given at the end.
We are done.
$\phantom{2}$

Proof of (5).
Let $s := \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)\cdot (k+1)}$. (5) is written as
$$F(s) := (1 + w_0^\alpha s)^\alpha - \frac{\frac{1}{s}}{\frac{1}{s} - \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)} \ge 0.$$
It it easy to prove that $F''(s) < 0$ on $(0, \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)}]$.
Also, $\lim_{s\to 0^{+}} F(s) = 0$. Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$F\left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + w_0^\alpha)}\right) \ge 0,$$
or
$$
 G(C) := \left(1 + \frac{C}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + C)}\right)^\alpha
 - 1 - \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ln(1 + C) \ge 0
$$
where $C := w_0^\alpha$. We have
$$G'(C) = \frac{a^2(Ca + C + a)\ln(1 + C) + a^3 + a^2}{(Ca + a\ln(1+C) + C + a + 1)(a\ln(1 + C) + a + 1)(1 + C)} \ge 0.$$
Also, $G(0) = 0$. Thus, $G(C) \ge 0$ for all $C \ge 0$.
We are done.
